# Backbone "new" Collection not creating new object

Tags: backbone.js

I have a single page app I am building that uses RequireJS and Backbone.
I have multiple data endpoints that I use Backbone to manage.

I have a collection that build a URL and appends a unique ID to the URL before it is fetched.

The collection is defined like this:

```
define([
'underscore',
'backbone', 
'models/MyModel'
], function(_, Backbone, MyModel){
console.log('test'+id);
var Data = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: MyModel,
  url: '/getData/?id='+id,
  parse: function(response) {
    return response;
  }
});        

return Data;
});
```

And it is used like this:

```
function retrieveData() {
require(['collections/MyData'],
    function(MyData) {
        // create model
        var data = new MyData(var:myVars});

        // fetch data
        data.fetch({async: false});

        //...
    }
);
```

}

All fairly straightforward.
However the problem I have arises when I am creating the model.
The Id that the URL uses to query the server changes in the background and I call retrieveData() when it does.
On the first pass of the code the model gets created and I have verified this as "console.log('test'+id);" prints to the console.
However, when I call retrieveData() again (after id changes), the code is executed to create a new model but instead of creating a new model, Backbone seems to return the already instantiated model from the first pass and therefore the URL does not get updated with the new id.
"console.log('test'+id);" does not print to the console on any pass bar the first as the object is not created and the function not entered.

Have I hooked something up working or is there some sort of caching going on here?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clean up your sample code? the way it looks right now, it has syntax errors and its hard to guess what the actual code looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you're trying to make your `id` when creating the collection prototype but the code that creates you `MyData` collection is only run once.

A better approach is probably to provide the `id` during instantiation.

Something like this:

```
define([
'underscore',
'backbone', 
'models/MyModel'
], function(_, Backbone, MyModel){
var Data = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: MyModel,
  initialize: function(options) {
    this.id = options.id;
  },
  url: function() {
    return '/getData/?id=' + this.id
  },
  parse: function(response) {
    return response;
  }
});        

return Data;
});
```

and

```
function retrieveData() {
require(['collections/MyData'],
    function(MyData) {
        // create model
        var data = new MyData({ var:myVars, id: id });

        // fetch data
        data.fetch({async: false});

        //...
    }
);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thats exactly the problem. Thanks, you wouldn't believe how long I've been looking at this issue!